# How do I download the RSS Feed XML file in dos command batch mode?

Tags: batch, ms-dos, rss

I have a specific requirement that I need to download the RSS feed file (it is in XML format) from the given link using dos command.

I have tried the following command and it keeps giving me syntax error.

```
E:\>wget -q -o wget.log https://www.myclienturl.com/arcio/factiva/?key=66gpsgbffay1gqybax4rfgiyty6dt09ysdghyhl & ren index.html@key=66gpsgbffay1gqybax4rfgiyty6dt09ysdghyh ProductFeed.xml
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

When I execute the wget command with the url, it is downloaded with the file name as
`index.html@key=66gpsgbffay1gqybax4rfgiyty6dt09ysdghyh`
and I am trying to rename that to a generic name so that I can use the file for further processing.

Also, I would like to add the following line on top of the downloaded file

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Please help or suggest any better way of achieving the same or help to identify where I am doing a mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0):

*UNTESTED*, suggested scripting:

Place the first line in a separate file e.g. `header.txt`

Do `wget -q -o wget.log -O download.txt URL...` to get the xml from the 'net

Do `copy header.txt + download.txt output.xml` to create what you need, stored in `output.xml`

*note: this is from memory, so the actual wget and copy options may need to be amended.*

`wget --help | more` - to find out wget options to use.
`copy /?` or even `help copy` - for the same w.r.t. copy.